# What is the name of this css/html feature?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If you go to this link http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/ 
youll find a demo of a bootstrap template known as agency. I want to use a feature of agency in my own html/css that allows the visitor to scroll down to a new view (kinda like a full page vertical slideshow) in the landing page to other views. What is the name of that feature?

Comment: You can also take a look at Parallax.js for fancy page scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure they are using the feature ScrollSpy.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#mdo

The example you show is using animations so its a couple different things. But the basic functionality acts like an anchor tag that goes to another part of the same page.